# Merging multiple arrays into a map

Tags: sql, arrays, dictionary, hive, hiveql

I have some data (sample from full table) that looks like this:

```
| prov_id | hotel_id | m_id | apis_xml | company_id | yyyy_mm_dd |
|---------|----------|------|----------|------------|------------|
| 945     | 78888    | 3910 | [5]      | 998        | 2020-05-20 |
| 1475    | 78888    | 6676 | [1,2,4]  | 37         | 2020-05-20 |
| 1475    | 78888    | 6670 | [1,2,4]  | 37         | 2020-05-20 |
| 945     | 78888    | 2617 | [5]      | 998        | 2020-05-20 |
```

I want to find the *lowest* apis_xml value per hotel and have the associated prov_id set as the "primary_prov". I can do this by merging and sorting the array ascending before taking the first row. I've got a query to this:

```
SELECT
    yyyy_mm_dd,
    hotel_id,
    prov_id as primary_prov
FROM(
    SELECT
        yyyy_mm_dd,
        hotel_id,
        prov_id,
        apis_xml,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY yyyy_mm_dd, hotel_id ORDER BY apis_xml) rn
    FROM(
        SELECT
            t.yyyy_mm_dd,
            t.hotel_id,
            t.prov_id,
            t.apis_xml,
            CAST(e.apis_xml AS INT) AS api
        FROM
            my_table t
        LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(apis_xml) e AS apis_xml
    )s
)s
WHERE rn=1
```

The above query works for getting the primary_prov which maps to the lowest apis_xml value. However, I want to have an extra column which contains the additional xml values for reference. Maybe a map is not the best use case here but it's what comes to mind. The key would be the prov_id while the value would be the apis_xml values. Output would look like this as I need to keep it to one row per hotel_id:

```
| hotel_id | primary_prov | detailed_prov            | yyyy_mm_dd |
|----------|--------------|--------------------------|------------|
| 78888    | 1475         | {1475: [1,2,4], 945: [5] | 2020-05-20 |
```

Comment: What is the data type of `detailed_prov`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I feel like a map might work best to store that type of data but I'm open to other solutions. In my output example, detailed_prov would be a map with <int,[arr]>

Comment: CAST(e.apis_xml AS INT) AS api - this column is not used at all. You ordering by whole array in the  row_number. If it is correct, then you do not need explode

Comment: @leftjoin good spot. I think I should be ordering by api rather than apis_xml as the primary_prov should be whichever prov_id has the lowest api number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build `map` using brickhouse CollectUDAF. Read [instructions how to build JAR](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse#getting-started), add jar, create function and use it:

```
add jar /path/to/jar/brickhouse-0.7.1.jar;
create temporary function collect as 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF';

SELECT yyyy_mm_dd,
       hotel_id,
       primary_prov,
       collect(prov_id, prov_id_api ) as detailed_prov
  FROM
(
SELECT
    yyyy_mm_dd,
    hotel_id,
    max(case when rn=1 then prov_id else null end) over(partition by yyyy_mm_dd, hotel_id) as primary_prov, 
    collect_set(api) over (partition by yyyy_mm_dd, hotel_id, prov_id) prov_id_api, --re-assemple array to include all elements from multiple initial arrays if there are different arrays per prov_id
    prov_id
FROM(
    SELECT
        yyyy_mm_dd,
        hotel_id,
        prov_id,
        apis_xml,
        api,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY yyyy_mm_dd, hotel_id ORDER BY api) rn
    FROM(
        SELECT
            t.yyyy_mm_dd,
            t.hotel_id,
            t.prov_id,
            t.apis_xml,
            CAST(e.apis_xml_element AS INT) AS api
        FROM
            my_table t
        LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(apis_xml) e AS apis_xml_element
    )s
)s
)s
group by yyyy_mm_dd,
         hotel_id,
         primary_prov
```

Comment: This works brilliantly, thank you! When creating the table, what type should I set 'detailed_prov' so the insert will work later? I want to avoid a type mismatch.

Comment: what is an output? I did not test it myself. If it really produces map<int,array<int>> Try to define that type. But It can produce map<String, array<int>> instead I guess... Just try to do it. Or try CREATE TABLE AS SELECT...