# Hive : How to aggregate over map column and return map

Tags: java, sql, hive, aggregate-functions, hiveql

I have a hive table as

```
create table tab(
col1 map<string,array<string>>)
```

it looks like

```
select key,value from tab lateral view explode(col1) e as key, value;

key |  value
-------------------
a   | ['1','2','3']
b   | ['4','5','6']
a   | ['7','8','9']
b   | ['12',11','12']
```

now i want to get the sum of the size of value for each key. i.e. i want to see something like this

```
{'a':6,'b':6}
```

i know i can do something like this

```
select key,sum(size(value)) from tab lateral view explode(col1) e as key, value group by key;
```

and it gives me

```
a 6
b 6
```

but i want the above result in a map as i am going to use it for an insert statement into my target table which is expecting a `map<string,int>`

how can i achieve this ?

i tried

```
select map(key,sum(size(value))) from tab lateral view explode(col1) e as key, value group by key;
```

but obviously it just gives me

```
{'a': 6}
{'b': 6}
```

Comment: not sure what else you need. the final query is correct where you get a `map<string,int>`

Comment: `{'a': 6}` is just the way Hive represents map in the shell, your query results in `map<string, bigint>`

Comment: my mistake. i updated the post. i want the final result as `{'a':6,'b':6}`

Comment: Use brickhouse colect UDAF: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62156562/2700344

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of standard Hive functions, you'll need the final `collect_list` aggregation and `str_to_map` UDF:

```sql
select str_to_map(concat_ws(',', collect_list(concat(t.key, ':', t.value)))) as result_map
  from (
    select key, sum(size(value)) as value
      from tab 
   lateral view explode(col1) e as key, value 
     group by key
     ) t
```

Also take a look at Brickhouse [Collect UDAF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24924185/9145106) ([direct link to the code](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect/CollectUDAF.java)): this might be more efficient than creating a string in the middle of transformations.